# How to place Ads on Apps Script Side Bar

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all is it legal to include ads in an app script side bar?

Adsense seems to be only for websites.

If yes, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to place ads inside Sidebars, if you are planning to publish your Apps Script as an add-on, Google may have a problem with it.

See their [Program Policy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/terms#add-ons) page.

> Google does not allow the serving of ads within Add-ons (including any
>   ads the Add-on hosts or links to).

Comment: Thanks. Therefore it is Illegal to put ads in a Sidebar of an App Script Add On